# Proving that the function set $\{ (2/l)^{1/2}\sin(n-\frac{1}{2})(\pi x/l) \}_1^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal set

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, fourier-analysis, orthonormal

I have the the following problem from my Fourier analysis book:

> Show that $\{ (2/l)^{1/2}\sin(n-\frac{1}{2})(\pi x/l) \}_1^{\infty}$
>   is an orthonormal set in $PC(0,l)$, i.e. class of piecewise continuous
>   functions on the interval $[0,l]$.

The dot product between two functions $\phi_n$, $\phi_m$ $\in PC(0,l)$ is defined as:

$$\langle\phi_n, \phi_m\rangle = \int_0^l\phi_n\, \overline{\phi_m}\:dx.$$

So my problem is to show that:

$$\langle\phi_n, \phi_m\rangle = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : m=n\\
       0 & : m\neq n
     \end{array}\right\}.$$

My problem is that I get confused with the complex conjugate $\overline{\phi_m}$. What is the complex conjugate of $$\phi_m = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sin\left( \frac{m\pi x}{l}-\frac{\pi x}{2l}\right)}{\sqrt{l}} \;\;\;(= \overline{\phi_m}\;\;?)$$

Should I use the identity $$\sin\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$

in this problem?

Thnx for any hints =)

Comment: Since the functions phi_n and phi_m are real, you can use the definition of dot product for real valued functions.  In that case, complex conjugate of real valued function is real.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @Oliver I did what you said and I got it solved =)

Comment: Good to hear that. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\langle \phi_n , \phi_m \rangle = \frac{2}{l}\int^l_0 \left[\sin\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2l}\right)\sin\left( \frac{(2m-1)\pi x}{2l}\right)\right]\;dx $$

$$=\frac{1}{l}\int^l_0 \left[ \cos\left( \frac{(n-m)\pi x}{l}\right)-\cos\left( \frac{(n+m-1)\pi x}{l}\right)  \right]\;dx \;\;\;\text{(by the product-to-sum rule)}$$

when $n=m$, the integral evaluates to:

$$=\frac{1}{l}\int^l_0 \left[ 1-\cos\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{l}\right)  \right]\;dx =\frac{1}{l}\left[ x-\frac{l}{(2n-1)\pi}\sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{l}\right)\right]^l_0 = \frac{1}{l}\cdot l = 1$$

when $n\neq m$, the integral evaluates to:

$$=\frac{1}{l}\left[ \frac{l}{(n-m)\pi }\sin\left( \frac{(n-m)\pi x}{l}\right)-\frac{l}{(n+m-1)\pi }\sin\left( \frac{(n+m-1)\pi x}{l}\right)  \right]^l_0 =\frac{1}{l}\cdot 0=0$$